# Supplying secrets to a rego Gatekeeper policy when doing an http.send() call?

Tags: kubernetes, opa, rego

[The documentation here](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#http) explains how the *http.send()* method can be used to make GET requests to external data sources. However for calls to internal sources the request would require a token of some kind to be supplied.

Is there a way of doing this in a secure manner such that the token is not hard-coded into the body of the policy? For instance calling on it when the policy is called to check against a request.

As I am using Gatekeeper from a Kubernetes environment, my idea was of mounting a file containing the secret to the pod running Gatekeeper, but that seems a bit overkill and still prone to breaches so wanted to see if there is a better way of handling things?